# Termux не получается запустить Angular приложение

Tags: webpack, консоль, unix, angular-cli, termux

Я пытаюсь запустить сервер для разработки Angular приложения в консоли Termux [ссылка](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=ru)
Не получается. Всё зависает на `92% additional asset processing copy-webpack-plugin`.
Разрешил приложению доступ к памяти телефона

Перед этим я задал папке с проектом `chmod 777 app-angular` и всем файлам внутри `chmod -R 777 app-angular/*` на всякий случай.
Как я прочитал в интернете, проблема может быть в настройках webpack'a. 
Но я не нашёл как настраивать webpack, вроде как, через angular.json, но я плохо понимаю что там менять.
У меня получилось запустить приложение на React и Vue, всё успешно, но с Angular не идёт
Подскажите куда копать, что может помочь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]